# SharePoint 2013 Multiple related list setup

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

**Situation:**

I have created 3x lists and these are as follows)

1. Projects
2. Issues
3. Risks

The above lists are related using lookups from both Issues and Risks using(ProjectID) to Projects list.

I have located a script that is applied to the Display form on the Parent to create new items on Issues with ProjectID auto populated for the use when the variable is passed to the new Issue form.

**The Problem:**

The display form for Projects includes Issues and Risks web parts with connections and filters to display only items relevant to that project however since the script changes the behaviour of the New item link on the web part it ends up pointing both links to the same location in this case Issues.

The current method will not work since both buttons to new items have the same class name or ID therefore I need to add some other button on my own with a unique identifier so that the they act independently.

Sorry about the long text and for any confusion. Happy to explain further.

Any help is highly appreciated

**Code:**

- Display form (Projects)

  ```
      <!--
      Name: dispParent.js
  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://samplesite/SiteAssets/Avanti/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      //get the ID for the Issue from the Query String
      var projectID = getParameterByName("ID");
      //find the element with the "Add new item" link.
      //note that if you have more than one list on your page, this just finds the first one
      var anchorElement = $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']");
      //modify the "Add new item" link to call the "NewItem2" function and pass in the Issue ID. 
     //Be sure to put the path to your site below. You can use relative URL to the web application or the FQDN
      $(anchorElement).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://samplesite/test/Lists/ProjectIssues/NewForm.aspx?ProjectID="  + projectID + "');");
      //remove the "onclick" attribute from the anchor element as we aren't using it anymore
      $(anchorElement).removeAttr("onclick");
  });
  // The following function should really be put into a utility library
  // with all of your commonly called functions
  //
  // no, I didn't write this function from scratch, I found it at
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript
  function getParameterByName(name)
  {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
      return "";
    else
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
  </script>
  ```
- New form (Issues and Risks)

  ```
      <!--
      Name: newChild.js 
  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      //get the Issue ID from they query string
      var projectID = getParameterByName("ProjectID");
      //Set the corresponding Lookup field value to the Issue ID
         $("select[title='Project Name']").val(projectID);    
         //use this line to disable the lookup field selection
         //$("select[title='Project Name']").attr('disabled','disabled')
         //use this line to hide the lookup field and label entirely
         //$("select[title='Project Name']").closest("tr").hide();
  if (projectID !=="") {
     $("select[title='Project Name']").attr('disabled','disabled')
  } 
  else {
    $("select[title='Project Name']").attr('enabled','enabled')
  }
  });
  // no, I didn't write this function from scratch, I found it at
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript
  function getParameterByName(name)
  {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
      return "";
    else
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
  </script>
  ```